# Indexing does not work with LIKE and NOT operator in Sql Server, Is it a MYTH

Tags: sql, sql-execution-plan

I have seen in many articles on Sql Server which states that when we are writing a query we should avoid using NOT and LIKE operator in our query because indexing is not applied on it.

eg.

```
  SELECT [CityId]
      ,[CityName]
      ,[StateId]
  FROM [LIMS].[dbo].[City]
  WHERE CityId NOT IN(1, 2)
```

I executed above query and found that indexing was getting used to filter the records.
Following is the execution plan, which clearly shows Clustured Index seek. This clearly violates what I used to think and read.

[image]

Was my previous understanding incorrect ?

Comment: it depends on search terms.. i.e. for LIKE operator, check this article... 
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel: Already saw that article. In my office as well, I saw the document which clearly states that avoid NOT and LIKE operator. LIKE is pretty understandable.. but why indexing won't be used this part is difficult to digest for me.

Comment: Well, for LIKE if search starts with % then there is no point of using an index what-so-ever. Otherwise, using index is very plausible since search string has fixed characters to begin with. Like John said, any database will go for best method available according to its algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That indexing does not work with LIKE and NOT operators is just a rule of thumb. SQL Server (or any competent RDBMS, for that matter) will use the best algorithm it can in **most** cases. So, if *you* could manually seek an index, so could SQL Server.

In the particular example you provided, it is unclear whether a seek is any more efficient than a scan because most of the records are going to be returned anyhow. So, I wouldn't read much into that particular execution plan.

**Bottom line**: Learn and understand how your database system internally organizes data and indices so you won't have to rely on rules of thumb.